# instagram api get all likes count

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, instagram

It possible to get all likes count to user? if yes please write api

and get user which most mark "likes" to user? if yes please write api

I not found on official dev site appropriate api.

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct endpoint to get that, you'll need to loop through each media item from a user's feed. Have a look at InstagramKit, https://github.com/shyambhat/InstagramKit, in case you're looking for an easier way to make these API calls.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your problem, you should look here: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

Look for this endpoint: /users/self/media/liked

Example url: https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

From there, you can query that endpoint like other endpoints and get the user's liked media.